# google map cant be displayed in a modal unless I had inspected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

i just put  in a modal a `<div id = maps>` and my function is

`function myFunction(){
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('agence-map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
$('#myModal').modal('show');
}`

when the modal is displayed the map cant be displayed unless i inspect any element.
So is there any solution ?

Comment: Probably it doesn't load, because the map container is not visible and has no width/height. Try to create the map after the modal is shown. `$("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() { /* initialize map here */ });`

Comment: I'm pretty sure inspecting an element causes a repaint in chrome. Does resizing the window also cause the map to display?